# What is the difference between using "EXTI_IRQHandler" and "EXTI_Callback"?

Tags: c, stm32, hal

I am using HAL library for my project with STM32 microcontroller.

In the sample code provided by STM, they use `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` for a push button interrupt. However, I learned in class that we need to use the IRQHandler to handle the interrupt.

So my question is when we use `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` and `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler` to handle interrupt?

Comment: AFAIK, `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler` needs to do stuff like mark the interrupt as handled. `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` Is just a function that gets called at the interrupt, with no particular responsibilities\.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ST's example projects, there are several function calls for a single interrupt:

- the interrupt handler itself is called `EXTI15_10_Handler`. It is the function whose address is specified in the vector table. It is the generic handler for the interrupt line EXTI15_10 and by default it is "routed" to a default function doing nothing. As it is a weak symbol you can redefine it as you want.
- if you are using EXTI15_10 interrupt line with standard GPIOs, `EXTI15_10_Handler` should call `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler`. This is a function provided by the HAL.
- the latter function is clearing the IT flag and then calls `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback`, which is also a weak function that is doing nothing by default. This is the function that you need to implement to process your GPIO.

Comment: Thank you for the clear breakdown. Is there any reason why you wouldn't just process your GPIO in `EXTI15_10_Handler`. I understand why you need to call `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler`. This resets bits and cleans stuff up, but I don't really understand why the HAL encourages you to do further GPIO handling  through a convoluted callback. What's the advantage?

Comment: @geokon the benefit of a callback is that the HAL user does not need to bother about  clearing appropriate flag at the right time but only about the interruption management.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't quite understand. Again, `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler` should be called and it will clear flags for you. Whether you do GPIO configuration in the extra `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback` that's provided or in the original handler (`EXTI15_10_Handler`) wouldn't the effect be exactly the same? You just need to make sure to call  `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler`. Or is the HAL in some kind of intermediate state during the `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback`? Where some flags are reset and others are not..

Comment: The effect would be the same, it is only a matter of software engineering. With callbacks the interface between HAL and user code is cleaner , the software is easier to maintain, etc...